# Oracle SQL ORA-06550 & PLS-00103 Errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, ora-06550, pls-00103

When running the code at the bottom of this post, I receive the following error report. Could someone please point out to me where the issue(s) lies? Thank you for your help.

Error report -

```
ORA-06550: line 12, column 8: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  number_of_payments    NUMBER(2);        --Total number of payments
  payment_num           NUMBER(2);           --Current payment number of total
  starting_date         DATE;                  --start date of payment
  ending_due            DATE;                    --due date of payment
  monthly_payment_amt   NUMBER(8,2); --monthly amt due
  donation_balance      NUMBER(8,2);     --remaining balance after pay
  pledgeamt             NUMBER(8,2);            --total amt to pay over term
BEGIN
  SELECT pledgeamt,
         pledgedate,
         paymonths INTO
    pledgeamt,starting_date,number_of_payments
  FROM dd_pledge
  WHERE idpledge = &idpledge;

  monthly_payment_amt := pledgeamt / number_of_payments;
  ending_due := starting_date;
  donation_balance := ( pledgeamt - monthly_payment_amt );
  payment_num := 0;
  LOOP
    payment_num := payment_num + 1;
    ending_due := add_months(ending_due,1);
    dbms_output.put_line('Payment number: '
    || payment_num
    || ' Due Date: '
    || ending_due
    || ' Payment Amount: '
    || monthly_payment_amt
    || ' Balance: '
    || TO_CHAR(donation_balance,'$9999.99') );

    donation_balance := donation_balance - monthly_payment_amt;
    EXIT WHEN donation_balance < 0; --LOOP until condition is met
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: "Everything that has a BEGINning, needs an END" ?

Comment: ps; if you indent stuff, these things are easier to see ;)

Comment: Might be helpful to look at the manual section about blocks of code: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/overview.html#GUID-826B070B-4888-4398-889B-61A3C6B91349

Comment: my bad. i copied and pasted wrong, leaving out the end; - still an error, though

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. *table or view does not exist* is self-explanatory, and line 12 is `FROM DD_PLEDGE`, which is the only place in the SQL you posted that would be trying to use a table or view. We don't know whether you have a *table or view* named *DD_PLEDGE*, but presumably you would. Do you have a table or view named *DD_PLEDGE*?

Comment: If you have a DD_PLEDGE table/view, it must be a grant issue